# Why could not parse YAML metadata?

Tags: yaml, pandoc

I can't generate my  "beautiful" document with pandoc (`.md` --> `.pdf`): my doc is ugly. The margins are much too wide, my texts cut off, etc...

The error message with pandoc is:

```
could not parse in YAML metadata at line 10 column 1 : :2:23 expected start of line
```

I checked that no space exists but I can't find the problem in my `.md`:

```
title: "Chapitre 5 :  "Architecture des ordinateurs"
subtitle: "C5_2 L'algèbre de Boole et les circuits combinatoires"
papersize: a4  
geometry: margin=1.5cm  
fontsize: 12pt  
lang: fr  

----

# L'algèbre de Boole

## Un peu d'histoire  

C'est le mathématicien britannique **George Boole** qui a réalisé cette algèbre à l'aube du 20-ème siècle. Boole a noté des similitudes
```

Comment: Please expand your question as it's not very clear what are you actually asking.

Comment: In the first line the second double quote (`"`) denotes the **end of the value**. Everything after it (`Architecture des ordinateurs"`) makes the YAML invalid. You may find that with any online YAML checker.

Answer (score 2):

The YAML block needs to start with `---` and end with `---` or `...`.  So, add `---` to the start of the YAML block and it should work.

Comment: pandoc does not support the use of `---` as horizontal line, use 4 or more. (because it is used to detect YAML block.